# Google Or tools Employee scheduling based on required number of employees to work in that shift

Tags: c#, scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

I am having an issue regarding scheduling in google or tools.

I am trying to build scheduler based on how many employees needed for a shift so during the day I need 10 and then from 17:00 to 20:00 (night shift) I may need anything from 10% to 100% of the employees working.

They can work a minimum from 8 hours a day to 12 hours.
They can work a minimum of 45 hours a week to 60 hours a week,
They can work a max of consecutive days then they need a day off.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class ShiftSchedulingSat
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SolveShiftScheduling();
    }

    static void SolveShiftScheduling()
    {
        int numEmployees = 15;
        int numWeeks = 1;
        //Shift day "0" day off
        //Shift day "8" hours for the day
        //Shift day "12" hours for the day
        var shifts = new[] { "0", "8", "12" };
        var numDays = numWeeks * 7;
        var numShifts = shifts.Length;
        LinearExprBuilder obj = LinearExpr.NewBuilder();

        //The Demands needed
        var weeklyCoverDemands = new int[][] {
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Monday
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Tuesday
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Wednesday
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Thursday
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Friday
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Saturday
            new[] { 12, 12 }, // Sunday
        };

        var model = new CpModel();

        BoolVar[,,] work = new BoolVar[numEmployees, numDays, numShifts];

        foreach (int e in Range(numEmployees))
        {
            foreach (int d in Range(numDays))
            {
                foreach (int s in Range(numShifts))
                {
                    work[e, d, s] = model.NewBoolVar($"work{e}_{d}_{s}");
                }
            }
        }
        // Max 3 days
        foreach (int e in Range(numEmployees))
        {
            foreach (int d in Range(2, numDays-2))
            {
                foreach (int s in Range(numShifts))
                {
                    model.AddBoolOr(new ILiteral[] { work[e, d - 2, s], work[e, d, s].Not(), work[e, d + 2, s] });
                }
            }
        }




        // number of required employees for shift 8 hours.

        foreach (int e in Range(numEmployees))
        {
            var temp = new BoolVar[numEmployees];
            foreach (int d in Range(numDays))
            {
                    temp[e] = work[e, d, 1]; 
            }
            model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(temp) == 12);
        }

        // 1 Type of shift per day.

        foreach (int e in Range(numEmployees))
        {
         
            foreach (int d in Range(numDays))
            {
                var temp = new BoolVar[numShifts];
                foreach (int s in Range(numShifts))
                {
                    temp[s] = work[e, d, s];
                }

                model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(temp) == 1);
            }
        }



        // Objective
        model.Maximize(obj);

        // Solve model
        var solver = new CpSolver();
        solver.StringParameters = "num_search_workers:8, log_search_progress: true, max_time_in_seconds:30";

        var status = solver.Solve(model);

        // Print solution
        if (status == CpSolverStatus.Optimal || status == CpSolverStatus.Feasible)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            var header = "          ";
            for (int w = 0; w < numWeeks; w++)
            {
                header += "M T W T F S S ";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(header);

            foreach (int e in Range(numEmployees))
            {
                var schedule = "";
                foreach (int d in Range(numDays))
                {
                    foreach (int s in Range(numShifts))
                    {
                        if (solver.BooleanValue(work[e, d, s]))
                        {
                            schedule += shifts[s] + " ";
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"worker {e}: {schedule}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Penalties:");


            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Statistics");
            Console.WriteLine($"  - status          : {status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  - conflicts       : {solver.NumConflicts()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  - branches        : {solver.NumBranches()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  - wall time       : {solver.WallTime()}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Filters an isolated sub-sequence of variables assigned to True.
    /// Extract the span of Boolean variables[start, start + length), negate them,
    /// and if there is variables to the left / right of this span, surround the
    /// span by them in non negated form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="works">A list of variables to extract the span from.</param>
    /// <param name="start">The start to the span.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The length of the span.</param>
    /// <returns>An array of variables which conjunction will be false if the
    /// sub-list is assigned to True, and correctly bounded by variables assigned
    /// to False, or by the start or end of works.</returns>
    static ILiteral[] NegatedBoundedSpan(BoolVar[] works, int start, int length)
    {
        var sequence = new List<ILiteral>();

        if (start > 0)
            sequence.Add(works[start - 1]);

        foreach (var i in Range(length))
            sequence.Add(works[start + i].Not());

        if (start + length < works.Length)
            sequence.Add(works[start + length]);

        return sequence.ToArray();
    }

    


    /// <summary>
    /// C# equivalent of Python range (start, stop)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">The inclusive start.</param>
    /// <param name="stop">The exclusive stop.</param>
    /// <returns>A sequence of integers.</returns>
    static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int stop)
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(start, stop - start))
            yield return i;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// C# equivalent of Python range (stop)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stop">The exclusive stop.</param>
    /// <returns>A sequence of integers.</returns>
    static IEnumerable<int> Range(int stop)
    {
        return Range(0, stop);
    }
}
```

I tried following this [ShiftSchedulingSat](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/dotnet/ShiftSchedulingSat.cs) guide

But keep getting infeasible results if add my constraints

Any suggestion? Could it be modelled in another way?

Comment: Create a toy dataset, verify that the problem is feasible manually. Add some slack or remove constraints, until you find the wrong code/assumption.

Comment: The sets we have show that it can work and currently are. Just need to write a solver to do this automatically, I need the to understand the models, constraints which is what I am struggling with.